# How to iterate over array and add each 3 items into a new Div

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, iterator

so I have an array of 100 objects which are mobile phones description. Now what I want to do is to display all the objects on the page with every 3 items in a new div with classname **row**.

I tried using for-of loop but I can't make logic of adding only 3 items and then making a new div for other 3 items.

Here is what I want to achieve (JSX):

```
<div className="row">
  <Mobile deviceName={mobile.DeviceName} />
  <Mobile deviceName={mobile.DeviceName}/>
   <Mobile deviceName={mobile.DeviceName}/>
 </div>
 <div className="row">
    <Mobile deviceName={mobile.DeviceName} />
    <Mobile deviceName={mobile.DeviceName}/>
    <Mobile deviceName={mobile.DeviceName}/>
 </div>
 <div className="row">
   <Mobile deviceName={mobile.DeviceName} />
   <Mobile deviceName={mobile.DeviceName}/>
   <Mobile deviceName={mobile.DeviceName}/>
  </div>
```

This is what I have done so far

```
    {
    this.state.mobiles.map(mobile => {
    return (
      <div className="col col-md-4 col-sm-1">
       < Mobile 
       key={mobile.DeviceName}
       deviceName={mobile.DeviceName}
       />
      </div> )
     })
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try formatting the array of 100 objects into a nested array structure first then mapping through the arrays?

```
renderMobiles = () => {
  let formattedArray = []
  let arrayOfThrees = []
  this.state.mobiles.forEach((mobile) => {
    if(arrayOfThrees.length < 3) {
    // If there is less than 3 items in the arrayOfThrees then push the mobile object into it
      arrayOfThrees.push(mobile)
    } else {
      // If there is more than 3 items in the arrayOfThrees
      // 1. Push the arrayOfThrees into the formattedArray (nested array)
      formattedArray.push(arrayOfThrees)
      // 2. Reset the arrayOfThrees with new mobile object (ie. it will go from 3 objects to 1 new object)
      arrayOfThrees = [mobile]
    }
  })

  formattedArray = [...formattedArray, arrayOfThrees]

  return formattedArray.map(arrayOfThrees => {
    let rowContent = arrayOfThrees.map(mobile => <Mobile deviceName={mobile.DeviceName} />)
    return(
      <div className="row">
        {rowContent}
      </div>
    )
  })
}
```